# Find index by breakpoints instead of multiple else if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, indexing

I am trying to generate sizes based on a persons height. For the moment my program works but I would like to find a shorter way to get the size instead of using all these `else if` statements. I would like to loop through "breakpoints" to find the corresponding index.

This is my original code + what i had in mind.

```js
const sizes = ['xxs', 'xxs or xs', 'xs', 'xs or s'] // Goes on for all sizes...

function generateSize(height) {
    let size;

    if (height < 142) {
        size = sizes[0];
    } else if (height >= 142 && height < 148) {
        size = sizes[1];
    } else if (height >= 148 && height < 154) {
        size = sizes[2];
    } else if (height >= 154 && height < 160) {
        size = sizes[3]; // Goes on for all sizes...
    } else {
        size = 'larger...';
    }

    return size;
}



// Example of what I had in mind.
const heightBreakpoints = [142, 148, 154, 160];
function getByBreakpoints(breakpoints, height){ // Part where I am stuck.
    let index;
    // Loop through breakpoints...
    return index;
}
const sizeIndex = (getByBreakpoints(heightBreakpoints, 158));
const s = sizes[sizeIndex];
```

Comment: It seems that your height options differ by 6 each time (148-142 = 6; 154-148 = 6; etc.). If that is the case, just use a loop.

Comment: @JayNyxed No. If it is the case that they are equidistant, one should use a simple division. No loop needed.

Comment: "*`// Something like this.`*" - yes, that's looking good! Can you show us your attempt at [using a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), please? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify this greatly just by tweaking your starting data structure. What if we had an array of objects that tie together size and its breakpoint:

```
const sizeMap = [
    { maxHeight: 142, size: 'xxs' },
    { maxHeight: 148, size: 'xxs or xs' },
    { maxHeight: 154, size: 'xs' },
    { maxHeight: 160, size: 'xs or s' },
]

const getSize = height => sizeMap.find(item => height < item.maxHeight).size

console.log(getSize(143))
```

Array function `find` returns the first value that satifsies your condition. The precondition for this approach to work is to have your array object's heights in ascending order.

Comment: @B4ndy did this help you ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const sizes = ['xxs', 'xxs or xs', 'xs', 'xs or s', "even another one here"]
// Goes on for all sizes...

function generateSize(height){
    let size;
    let left = 142;
    let right = 142;
    // Initialize the variables for comparison
    // Left and right comparison based on position of "&"
    // This is just user-defined
    for(var i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++){
       if(height < right){
        size = sizes[i];
        return size;
       }
       else {
          // add counter from here
          // This takes us to the next item in the array
          i += 1;
          // add right comparison with intervals of 6
          right += 6;
            if(height >= left && height < right){
               size = sizes[i];
               return size;
            }
            else {
             // add left comparison with intervals of 6
             left += 6;
             // revert the counter to its initial value
             i -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log("First: " + generateSize(141))
console.log("Second: " + generateSize(147))
console.log("Third: " + generateSize(153))
console.log("Fourth: " + generateSize(159))
console.log("Last: " + generateSize(161));
// Note this 161, which will return the new last value in the array
```

This assumes your sizes are at intervals of 6, (which they are) and returns respective values corresponding to the array

Answer (score -1):

```
if(height<160){
height-=142;
if(height<0){size=sizes[0]}
else{
size=sizes[(hieght)%6]
}
}
else{
size='larger...'
}
```

check if this works in all cases I am sleepy